# Vagrant : phpUnit not found (symfony 2.8)

Tags: phpunit, vagrant, composer-php, symfony-2.8

**I'm new to phpUnit**. I installed it via composer. My composer.json is the following :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "^2.8",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
    "nicmart/tree": "~0.2",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
    "simple-bus/symfony-bridge": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit":">=4.2",
    "codeception/codeception": "*",
    "nicolopignatelli/valueobjects": "^4.0"

},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^2.7"
    }
```

during `composer update`, i recieved
     - Installing phpunit/phpunit (5.2.9)

and i see the phpunit directory in my vendors.

now while simply trying to output the phpunit version (or while trying to start testing), i get the following error message :

`me@myMachine:root/path/of/symfony$ phpunit -v
       The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed. To run 'phpunit' please ask your administrator to install the package 'phpunit'`

**is there any kind of shortcut to create in bash?**

**UPDATE**

like suggested by the 2 current answers, i tried to run `me@myMachine:root/path/of/symfony$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit -v`

but it returns a `permission denied` exception despite the fact the current user (me@myMachine) is the fileowner.

furthermore, `me@myMachine:root/path/of/symfony$ ls -l ./vendor/bin` returns

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 612 Mar  1 09:52 codecept
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 603 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 609 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine-dbal
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me  607 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 608 Feb 24 19:20 geotools
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 603 Mar  1 09:52 phpunit
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 978 Jan 20 12:15 security-checker
```

and if try to `chmod -vR u+x ./vendor/bin` it returns as expected a

`mode of ‘bin/’ changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0766 (rwxrw-rw-)`

`mode of ‘bin/phpunit’ changed from 0666 (rw-rw-rw-) to 0766 (rwxrw-rw-)`

but `me@myMachine:root/path/of/symfony$ ls -l ./vendor/bin` **returns again**

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 612 Mar  1 09:52 codecept
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 603 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 609 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine-dbal
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me  607 Jan 28 13:50 doctrine.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 608 Feb 24 19:20 geotools
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 603 Mar  1 09:52 phpunit
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 978 Jan 20 12:15 security-checker
```

like the chmod wasnt taken into account.

**UPDATE 2**

**apparently, this issue is related to Vagrant.**

I re-installed symfony completly, in 2.8 and 3.0 version, and the problem remains the same.

i found [this similar issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/phpunit-command-not-found) and therefore choosed to install phpUnit globally `composer global require phpunit/phpunit` and then run `phpunit -v` again. This time, the command is found but i got the following error

```
me@myMachine:/path/to/symfony/root$ phpunit -v
PHPUnit 4.8.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Configuration:  /var/www/public/symfony/sgv3/sgv3/phpunit.xml.dist

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 6.86 seconds, Memory: 27.75Mb

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::warningCount() in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 185
```

Comment: shouldn't you line `"phpunit/phpunit":">=4.2",` be in `"require-dev"` ?

Comment: i tried that (even i f i can't see the correlation) but it has no effect.

Comment: You need to call the specific executable in the bin directory of your project like

    `bin/phpunit -h`

have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install PHPUnit via Composer then its binary will be at `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Comment: thanx for your answer but now i get `-bash: ./vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied`

Comment: but as expected whoami == fileowner (and group owner). It was a sf3.0 that i downgraded to 2.8, could that be related?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the specific binary in the vendor's bin directory of your project like

```
bin/phpunit -h
```

Comment: thanx for your answer. I now have a `-bash: ./vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied
`

Comment: try changing its mode to 766 `chmod -R 766 ./vendor/bin` or chown to the current user

Comment: before changing the whole directory rights, it tried to sudo the command at first and it doesnt work either : `sudo ./vendor/bin/phpunit` returns `command not found`

Comment: if it'sa binary, shouldnt'it be executable?

Comment: i'm really stuck. I did `chmod -v u+x phpunit`. It returns a `mode of ‘phpunit’ changed from 0666 (rw-rw-rw-) to 0766 (rwxrw-rw-)`. But `ls -l` returns again `rw-rw-rw-`. Like it's not taking the chmod into account. Same if i try to `chmod -R u+x ./vendor/bin` the whole directory

Comment: apparently a vagrant issue

Comment: I think its because of the type of your partition. But im not entirely sure.. Its another issue, so you need to research about it again.